# Cant connect to my AWS node server through secure (https) connection

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on a 2-player card game. The two client facing pages are hosted on Github pages and the node server is running on AWS.

Everything works fine when I view my client side pages locally, but when I try to open them on Github pages I get this error:

*Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

So then I change the connection url to include http**s** like this:

`var socket = io.connect("https://ec2-18-191-142-129.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000");`

And I get this error:

*index.js:83 GET https://ec2-18-191-142-129.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N71Cs6c net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR*

Here are my security groups:

[image: Security Groups]

Do I need to do something with an SSL certificate? Is it even possible with my current setup as I don't have access to the domain I am hosting on (Github Pages). If it's not possible are there any online services I can host my client code on and get an SSL certificate, or do I have to buy a domain and hosting? Any help welcome, but please try to explain it because I am very new to all this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Ec2 doesn't support https like this ("out of the box").

There is several way of doing it, but I suggest you should create a application load balancer (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) and then configure https on it (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html).

Other solution can be using Cloudfront, or configure https directly on the instance (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html).

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by alcyon, changing from HTTP to HTTPS does not enable your application to run over HTTPS. There are many ways to achieve this. Checkout the detailed guide by AWS for your use-case at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-acm-certificates-ec2/ .